# I found the following codebut when I tried to run the code it display a SyntaxError and I do not know why

Tags: python-3.x

I want to step through the code to see how it works and I will be grateful if somebody could help me to get the code to run.

def isPalindrome(word: str) -> bool:
    if(word == word[::-1]):
        return True
    return Falsedef getPalindromesFromStr(inputStr: str) -> list:
    cleanStr = inputStr.replace(",","").lower()
    words = set(cleanStr.split(" "))
    wPalindromes = [
        word for word in words 
        if isPalindrome(word) and word != ""
    ]
    return wPalindromesgetPalindromesFromStr(“Lol, this is a gag, I didn’t laugh so much in a long time”)

Comment: It's all a single long line. Python cannot handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to be brutally honest here: this code is terrible. It is all in one line, spaces are missing, the list goes on.

However, below is how the code should look if it were formatted correctly. This functions as it should.

```py
def isPalindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]

def getPalindromesFromStr(inputStr):
    cleanStr = inputStr.replace(",","").lower()
    words = set(cleanStr.split(" ")) 
    wPalindromes = [word for word in words if isPalindrome(word) and word != "" ]
    return wPalindromes

print(getPalindromesFromStr("Lol, this is a gag, I didn’t laugh so much in a long time"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pencilcaseman. I truly appreciate the time you spend on my question.

Comment: No problem PhyAH. If this solution works for you, you can mark this answer as accepted to more easily inform others of this solution. Glad this works for you